# Javascript send "this" object as parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, this

I would like to know if it is possible to pass an object as a parameter to another "class" in javascript.

For example

```
function parent = function() {
    var child = new child();
    this.child.setParent(this);
}
```

I know that example is redundant but I hope it gets the point across.

Comment: Yes, you can pass `this` as you are intending.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Your example is correct.

Some additional reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why wouldn't it be? It's a value just like anything else.

That said, `this` has occasionally-weird semantics in JavaScript, and you need to make sure it's binding to what you think it is, particularly when dealing with closures.